# How to upload images, and text that's associated with a product to firebase database manually

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I am working on an E-commerce application and I need to upload things such as product name, price, description along with an image of the product to the Firebase Realtime Database and then load it once the app is launched. I was planning on using 3 separate nodes that store items in one and item price in the next, then finally images of the product, but I am unsure as to how to store individual images inside a node that is associated with the products, is there a better way of doing this, that someone can share?

[image: Screenshot of my database.]

Comment: To understand better, the $49.99 price is for `Shirts`, right? And you want another node called `ItemsUrl` where `0` will hold the URL of the `Shirts`?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

I have asked you a question in the comments section:

> To understand better, the $49.99 price is for Shirts, right? And you want another node called `ItemsUrl` where `0` will hold the URL of the Shirts?

And you answered:

> Yes that's what I want to do

But please note that this is not the way you should interact with the Realtime Database. Storing each field into an array, in separate nodes, sounds not like the best solution. What I recommend you instead, is to create a single node of products, and add each field inside a separate product object:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- products
        |
        --- $pushedId
              |
              --- itemName: "Shirt"
              |
              --- itemPrice: "$49.99"
              |
              --- itemUrl: "https://..."
```

To read the data, you can then use one of my answers from the following posts:

- [How to retrieve all data from Firebase Realtime Database if I have the next structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847626/how-to-retrieve-all-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-if-i-have-the-next-stru)
- [Read data from firebase realtime database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487954/read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database)

Comment: Thank you for your response, so if my client have like 1000+ products that he/she is selling I would have to manually add those items under the products node? is there a better option u can recommend ? also for itemUrl if  my client have images, I would have to upload that image somewhere and get the item url for it inorder to load in app?

Comment: Yes, it should add 1000 products under that node. It's slightly better than adding each property into a separate array. Not to mention the operation to maintain those arrays. No, there is no better option in this case. And yes, for the images, you should upload them on a server you own or use [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage), which I highly recommend.

Comment: Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways:

1. Just add the public link in one your database field, of that image/file and access it.

   **Or**
2. You can add you image/file in firebase storage. And then you can access ot via your FirebaseStorage library.

And for the text part, you can just click on plus icon in database's field and write your desired field and its value.